# GlmmTMB giving error realted to log-likelihood

Tags: r, model, regression, glmmtmb

I tried to run the following glmmTMB model to include spatial autocorrelation:

```
glmmTMB(response ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + exp(coord + 0|random).
```

It gives this error:

```
Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) : negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values
```

I tried to include this term:

```
start = list(psi = c(-1, 0)
```

and update the package "Matrix" to the version 1.6.4, but nothing seems to work.

I anyone can help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any missing values in the data?

Comment: Yes, but I removed all of them before running the analysis.

Comment: did you make `coord` into a `numFactor`? Does the example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html#exponential) work for you?  If these hints don't work I think we're going to need a [mcve], e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes. I inserted as follows: data_total$coord = numFactor(data_total$x,data_total$y)